# Responsive fa-icon inside of input

Tags: css

Here is some code from a Treehouse-author showing how to place an icon inside of a input.

HTML:

```
<div class="search">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  <input placeholder="Search term">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
body {
  margin: 30px;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #ebebeb inset;
}

.search input {
  text-indent: 32px;
}

.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

And the pen that proves it:
http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/aBnbL#0

How can you put the icon at the end of the input and have it be responsive to a changing of the screen?

I tried using a percetage positioning the icon but it did not work at all.
Here is a fiddle with my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/x7j869g7/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give `display:inline-block;` and `position:relative` to `.search` and then align icon to the right side(`right: 10px`).

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/x7j869g7/5/)

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
 body {
  margin: 30px;
}
.search {
  position: relative;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.search input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #ebebeb inset;
}
.search input {
  text-indent: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you both! This answer was short and sweet and will be accepted ASAP. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
// browser reset
 body {
  margin: 30px;
}
.search {
  position: relative;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 250px;
}
.search input {
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #ebebeb inset;
}
.search input {
  padding-right: 32px;
}
.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="search">
  <input placeholder="Search term">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
</div>
```

You need to set the width of search div. and position it to right.