# How to make my search icon fixed?

Tags: html

I want the search icon to be inside the text box even when the screen size changes.
Here is my html code:----

```
<div class="row" id="about_search">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div id="searchCol_a" class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:10px!important;">
   <input class="form-control header-searchbar_a form-control-md width-220 pull-right" id="header-search_a" type="text" placeholder="Crazy about your career, search it...">
        <span class="icon">
            <i id="faSearch_a" class="fa fa-search" style="position: absolute"></i>
        </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer: (Responsive fa-icon inside of input)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081889/responsive-fa-icon-inside-of-input]

Comment: ill surely try it..thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
    @import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
.search { position: relative; }
.search input { text-indent: 30px;}
.search .fa-search { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

<div class="search">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  <input placeholder="Search term"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use Bootstrap [BS Inputs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) or Padding on SPAN, if you use CSS direcly its maybe not work correctly in RESPONSIVE mode, but Bootstrap provides valid solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this, probably the easiest solution(for me):

***EXAMPLE***

```css
label {
    position: relative;
}

.fa-search {
    top: 2px;
    left: 5px; /* for left side */
    /* right: 5px; for right side*/
    position: absolute;
}

#search {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="search">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="search..." />
</label>
```